# Breeze expand navigation property not populating array

Tags: asp.net-web-api, breeze, entity-framework-6

I am using Web API 2 with Breeze and Entity Framework 6.  I have the following models.

```
 public class ScoreCard: EntityBase
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public virtual List<ScoreCardSection> Sections { get; set; }

    public String UserId { get; set; }

}
public class ScoreCardSection:EntityBase
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int Index { get; set; }

    public long ScoreCardId { get; set; }

    public virtual List<ScoreCardQuestion> Questions { get; set; }
}
```

I want to fetch a score card with a list of sections.  I execute a EntityQuery with an expand and it executes this URL:

```
/api/ScoreCards?$filter=Id%20eq%201L&$expand=Sections
```

I get back the following results:

```
  [{"Title":"Catalyst Service Report","Sections":
[{"Title":"Worship","Index":0,"ScoreCardId":1,"Questions":null,"Id":1},
{"Title":"Message","Index":0,"ScoreCardId":1,"Questions":null,"Id":2},
{"Title":"Leader","Index":0,"ScoreCardId":1,"Questions":null,"Id":3},
{"Title":"Attendance","Index":0,"ScoreCardId":1,"Questions":null,"Id":4},
{"Title":"Security","Index":0,"ScoreCardId":1,"Questions":null,"Id":5}],
"UserId":"b9bd5256-dd18-4c1e-9907-dac9e7e4c01b","Id":1}]
```

So far, so good.  Now we get to the problem.  When I inspect the results during the success callback the sections property of the object is a empty array, even though the sections were sent back in the response.

What am I missing here?   Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the solution to this problem seemed to be a few hours sleep.

For anyone who has this same issue the first part of the problem was that I didn't have a navigation property for ScoreCard on ScoreCardSection.  Once I added that I got a "Self Referencing Loop" error.  This was corrected by adding the BreezeControllerAttribute to my controller class.

Hope this is helpful to someone.